# How to get entries submitted by users through Contact 7 Forms Plugin on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have made a contact 7 form, I need to get the list of the user's input (form's entries) in Wp-admin as a list.

I have tried using it without plugin, I do not want to use plugin. All I need it custom code, which can be integrated in Function.php.

Comment: Hi and welcome here. Maybe your question is out of the scope of SO. Here, you have to submit code you have written, with which you encounter a technical issue.